# Windows 11 - Sort pinned items in Quick Access not working

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, windows-10-quick-access

Since the 22H2 update (guessing) I cannot sort the items in the quick access ("Home") in the Windows file explorer anymore. I can add new folders (pin to quick access) - but it is always pinned at the end of the list.

Trying to re-sort the list with drag&drop, windows/the explorer only provide to move the folders into eachother.

Where is the quick access stored? As file or in the registry - maybe thus I can reorder the items editing the quick access there?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution is an option in the Explorer settings:

If the option "Show all folders" (1st one in Navigation) is set, the "home"-Areas is shown on top of the navigation's list and NOT SORTABLE.

If the option is unchecked, the "Home" on top is empty and items from "Home" (or Schnellzugriff in german) are shown below the OneDrive folders - and **are sortable** there.

[image]